# "Namespace is already defined" Error when using Group Policy Editor

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

I am having an issue with the following error appearing every time I open the group policy editor on my computer running Windows 10 Pro x64 with the November Update applied. I do not frequent the Policy Editor, so I do not know if this has been a long-standing issue that I never noticed or if this is a more recent issue.

Does anybody have an idea for a fix? I'm not sure if this could be related to corruption with my Component Store that I am trying to resolve at the moment.

[image: Group Policy Editor Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, everybody has it after 1511 update. It manifests itself on all machines *updated* to 1511, as opposed to *clean installations* of Windows 10 ver.1511. Machines with clean-installed Windows 10 ver.1511 do not have this issue.

Essentially the same problem has already popped up before in other version of Windows. It is described here (with the official fix)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3077013

See this thread for some Windows 10-specific details

http://www.tenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/30257-updated-1511-machines-gpedit-msc-reports-namespace-conflict.html

Answer (score 1):

Simple temporary fix assuming you don't need to change the geolocation settings: Move the file named in the message box out of `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\` to a back-up location, then restart the Group Policy Editor.